# Performing a check after period of time

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a block of code for a game I'm creating that will shoot a ball towards a target, and after a period of time check to see if the ball collided with the target. For the sake of simplicity I'm going to only include the portion that moves the ball and checks to see if they collided.

```
def answer():
    answergiven = simpledialog.askstring("angle", "Pick an angle", initialvalue="Enter a degree")
    dMove = game.create_oval(75, 25, 100, 50,fill="black")
    degree = (90 + int(answergiven))
    for i in range(50):
        game.move(dMove, math.sin(math.radians(degree))*10, \
                  -math.cos(math.radians(degree))*10)
        time.sleep(0.06)
        game.update()
        check()

def check():
    global tarx
    global tary
    global game
    end = game.find_overlapping(tarx-25, tary-25,tarx+25, tary+25)
    if len(end) >1:
        choice = simpledialog.askstring("Congratz", "You win! Try again? Y/N")
        if choice == "Y":
            game.delete(dMove)
            game.delete(tar)
            play()
        if choice == "N":
            master.destroy()
    else:
        choice1 = simpledialog.askstring("Drat", "You missed! Try again? Y/N")
        if choice1 == "Y":
            game.delete(dMove)
            game.delete(tar)
            play()
        if choice1 == "N":
            master.destroy()
```

Now the problem I'm running into is that the check performs immediately, rather than before the ball travels to the end of its path. How can I amend this to perform the check after a period of time?

Comment: Wild guess: Is your call to check() meant to be inside the for loop?

Comment: Oh my god I feel so silly now, thank you so much. I removed the indent before the check that was adding it to the loop and it worked beautifully. lol